# how do i add a "background color" behind my image

Tags: html, css

i am making a page of a website with images and im stuck at how do i add these blocks behind my image.

[this is what im trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGg6o.png)

html:

```
<section class="section">
        <h1>Restaurants in Ipoh</h1>
        <div class="r-container">  
            <div class="r-row">
                <div class="r-col">
                    
                    <p class="restaurants">
                    <a href="#"><img src="Images\lou-wong.jpg" width="500" height="300" /></a> <br>
                    </p>
                    
        
                    <p class="restaurants">
                    <a href="#"><img src="Images\foh-san.jpg" width="500" height="300" /></a> <br>
                    </p>
        
        
                    <p class="restaurants">
                    <a href="#"><img src="Images\tuck-kee.jpg" width="500" height="300" /></a> <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

css:

```
section{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.r-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #FFEB88;
    margin: auto;

    
}

.r-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.section {
    background-color: #FFEB88;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;

}

.r-col {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.restaurants {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

i've tried adding a background color into the section div and doesn't seem to work. so is there anyway i can add a block of color behind my images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have paragraph tags wrapping the image. Perhaps you want to add some text? But, I switched them to divs and added a background-color and width of 1000px to the .resturaunts class.

I think your problem was due to your image overflowing the size of your div/p, so the background color was not filling the entire background.

You can try placing the class I made on paragraph tags like you had in your initial post, or just nest them in the restaurant div that I created.  Change the padding size and width of the div in order to adjust the size of the background in each direction and you should be able to get the desired outcome.

```css
section{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.r-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #FFEB88;
    margin: auto;

    
}

.r-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.section {
    background-color: #FFEB88;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;

}

.r-col {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.restaurants {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color:black;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <h1>Restaurants in Ipoh</h1>
  <div class="r-container">
    <div class="r-row">
      <div class="r-col">

        <div class="restaurants">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="Images\lou-wong.jpg" width="500" height="300" />
          </a> 
          <br>
        </div>

        <div class="restaurants">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="Images\foh-san.jpg" width="500" height="300" />
          </a> 
          <br>
        </div>

        <div class="restaurants">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="Images\tuck-kee.jpg" width="500" height="300" />
          </a> 
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

I was able to get something similar to your desired result in the following code snippet. Using CSS grid.

```css
section{
    bottom: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #FFEB88;
}

.restaurant-card {
    display: grid;
    margin: 0 40px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
}

.restaurant-card img {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.restaurant-title {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  background-color: black;
}
.restaurant-description {
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <h1>Restaurants in Ipoh</h1>

  <div class="restaurant-card">
    <img src="https://www.foodadvisor.my/attachments/93b0caab98281d6946e3023bf6b5f84c3a8d65b1/store/fill/800/500/981827a7db727837e18b80cbdf07e146f18d3600be71a16cba28d650b9f8/featured_image.jpg" width="500" height="300" />
    <div>
      <p class="restaurant-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;Ipoh Lou Wong</p>
      <p class="restaurant-description">The 61-year old restaurant serves only checken rice and bean sprouts fried in Ipoh, Malaysia. Lou Won Restauraunt (Restoran Tauge Ayam Lou Wong, Lou Wong Opoh, Loud Wong Chicken Resturaunt) is one of the most attractive popular tourist places in the center of Opoh old town. It has to be the MOST famous of all Ipoh's restaunts, bar none.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="restaurant-card">
    <img src="https://www.foodadvisor.my/attachments/93b0caab98281d6946e3023bf6b5f84c3a8d65b1/store/fill/800/500/981827a7db727837e18b80cbdf07e146f18d3600be71a16cba28d650b9f8/featured_image.jpg" width="500" height="300" />
    <div>
      <p class="restaurant-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;Ipoh Tuck Kee</p>
      <p class="restaurant-description">The 61-year old restaurant serves only checken rice and bean sprouts fried in Ipoh, Malaysia. Lou Won Restauraunt (Restoran Tauge Ayam Lou Wong, Lou Wong Opoh, Loud Wong Chicken Resturaunt) is one of the most attractive popular tourist places in the center of Opoh old town. It has to be the MOST famous of all Ipoh's restaunts, bar none.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="restaurant-card">
    <img src="https://www.foodadvisor.my/attachments/93b0caab98281d6946e3023bf6b5f84c3a8d65b1/store/fill/800/500/981827a7db727837e18b80cbdf07e146f18d3600be71a16cba28d650b9f8/featured_image.jpg" width="500" height="300" />
    <div>
      <p class="restaurant-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;Ipoh Lou Wong</p>
      <p class="restaurant-description">The 61-year old restaurant serves only checken rice and bean sprouts fried in Ipoh, Malaysia. Lou Won Restauraunt (Restoran Tauge Ayam Lou Wong, Lou Wong Opoh, Loud Wong Chicken Resturaunt) is one of the most attractive popular tourist places in the center of Opoh old town. It has to be the MOST famous of all Ipoh's restaunts, bar none.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: is there anyway to move all 3 of the restaurant-card div more towards the center while keeping its size? ive tried putting left: px in the css and it would only move the left side and make the whole card smaller

Comment: @Koyomini  if you are using my solution with CSS grid, try adding justify-items:center; to the resturaunt-card class. If that doesn't work. Google/Youtube examples of "how to center a div using CSS grid". If you aren't using CSS grid. Try to set margin-left and margin-right to auto, or find some tutorials on centering without CSS grid.

Alternatively, you could place all three of the resturaunt-cards inside a new div. Call that one resturaunt-wrapper for example. Then make a new .resturaunt-wrapper class and center everything inside the wrapper div.